# Getting to a user's network profile on mobile site

Tags: support, profile-page, mobile-web

On the mobile version of a user's site profile page, how do you get to their network profile without switching to desktop mode? I couldn't find any links in the drop down, and I tried clicking various things, like their username, etc. but couldn't find a link to the network profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click/tap "X accounts":

[image: accounts]